# Logo on print style sheet

Tags: css, printing

I am creating a print stylesheet, but as the logo on the web pages is white with a transparent background I will need to replace it with another image on print.

I have used the code below and it works fine on my local install, however, when I push it to the server it does not display the header:before { content: url(images/WCC-logo.png); }

Obviously I am missing something, but I cannot see what.

```
@media print {
  * {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }

header:before { 
    content: url(images/WCC-logo.png);
} 
    a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
    .slide-out-div {display: none;}
    .slide-out-div-open {display: none;}
     #multiColumn {display: none;}
     #hero-header-button {display: none!important;}
     .accordion-slide-content {display: block!important}
     .pager li {display: none;}
     .post-edit-link {display: none;}
     .btn-danger {display: none;}
     .btn-big {display: none;}
     .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {display: none;} 
    .handle {display: none;}
    .section-header {display: none;}
    .entry-header-hero img {display: none;}
    #secondary {display: none;}
    #footer {display: none;}
    #footer-logos-bottom {display: none;}
    .textwidget {display: none;}
    /*.brand {display: block;}*/
    .entry-hero-button {display: none;}
    .print-page {display: none;}   
    #brand {display: block!important;}
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
        page-break-after:avoid;
     page-break-inside:avoid;
     page-break-inside: avoid; }
     h1 {font-size: 25px;}
     h2 {font-size: 20px;}
     h3 {font-size: 18px;}
     h4 {font-size: 15px;}
     .breadcrumb {display: none;}
 }
```

Thanks Dave

Comment: is the path images/WCC-logo.png correct also in the server?

Comment: Checked the path and yes it is the correct path on the sever.

Comment: All sorted now.  Needed to enter the file path of where the image is stored in the media library of Wordpress, not where it is on the server.  The correct filepath was header:before { 
    content: url(http://www.warwickshire.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/WCC-Logo.gif);